# Using a JoinTable

Tags: jakarta-ee, mapping, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, join

[image]

I'm trying to do a twitter-like project using Java2EE, and here's a simple view of the database.
Mention, Followers and Following are three JoinTable.
(Note that mentioned,follower,following and every user field have User.username as foreign key.)
I've got a problem with the first one, that causes my deploy to fail with this exception :

> Exception Description: The reference column name [username] mapped on the element [field mentions] does not correspond to a valid field on the mapping reference..

Here's the mapping for the two entities.

Tweet :

```
public class Tweet implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "username")
    @ManyToOne
    User user;
    @JoinTable(name = "Mention", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "tweet", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "mentioned", referencedColumnName = "username")})
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Tweet> mentions;
```

User :

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 50)

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Collection<Tweet> tweets;
    @JoinTable(name = "Following", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "username")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "following", referencedColumnName = "username")})
    @OneToMany
    Collection<User> following;
    @JoinTable(name = "Followers", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "username")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "follower", referencedColumnName = "username")})
    @OneToMany
    Collection<User> followers;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mentions")
    Collection<Tweet> mentioning;
```

What's wrong with my mapping?
Can someone point me to the solution?

Comment: It would be nice of you to perhaps remove annotations that are irrelevant to mapping, I think much of this code is irrelevant to the question and fix the indentation etc :-)

Comment: Fixed. I've left some mappings in User's class because they may be wrong too :)

Comment: `Mention.mentioned` should be referenced by `User.username`.
`Following` doesn't have a `username` field but it works with this mapping, that's quite the same for `Mention`

Comment: `Following` is mapped ok because, for want of a better explanation `username` is a field within the class the mapping resides i.e. it is defaulted to being `User.username`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change

```
@JoinColumn(name = "mentioned", referencedColumnName = "username")
```

to specify the user table

```
@JoinColumn(name = "mentioned", referencedColumnName = "user")
```

As basically the message is saying that your `tweet` table doesn't have a foreign key field `username` which it doesn't as you have called it `user`

This -> `private Collection<Tweet> mentions;` should also be a one to many collection of users leaving you with

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "Mention", 
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "tweet", referencedColumnName = "id")
    }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "mentioned", referencedColumnName = "user")
    }
)    
private Collection<User> mentions;
```

Comment: Already tried with `referencedColumnName = "user"` but the error is the same !
I don't understand the first option you said

Comment: Using the second one leads to the same error as before :/
With the first one, now I've got this message : `Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class entity.User] and [class entity.Tweet]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer`

Comment: Ignore the first way I mentioned that was wrong, have you tried changing both the `referenceColumnName` and `Collection<T>` to user

Comment: Yes, but it still fails with the same error.
Can you please write the mapping here for both the entities?

Comment: Unless I'm blind, my code is the same as yours..Still getting the same error as the first post

Tweet

`@JoinTable(name = "Mention",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "tweet", referencedColumnName = "id")},    
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "mentioned", referencedColumnName = "user")})
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<User> mentions;`

User

`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mentions")
    private Collection<Tweet> mentioning;`